# How to update current branch to the state of master?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-bash, pull-request

I'm new to git, so this may have been answered somewhere else, but I honestly don't know how to phrase my search so that it doesn't sound like I just want to push my branch to master.

We have the master branch and two other branches, branches A and B.

I made some changes in branch A and committed them to master.

Now master is identical to my current branch A.

Then my friend, who was working on branch B, makes some changes and commits those to master. We were working on separate files so there are no merge conflicts.

But now my branch A is not the same as master.

How do I get the changes that he made into my branch? I've tried pulling and checking out but Git Bash keeps telling me that branch A is "already up to date." What am I supposed to do here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout A
git merge origin/master
```

This is merging the master branch into your feature branch.

In Git, "origin" is a shorthand name for the remote repository that a project was originally cloned from. (from [gittower.com](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/glossary/origin#:%7E:text=In%20Git%2C%20%22origin%22%20is,but%20just%20a%20standard%20convention.))

Another (maybe not so practical) option could be to locally checkout master first and pull:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout A
git merge master
```

In this case, you pull (fetch and merge) master from origin. Then your local master is merged into your feature branch.

Many people use rebase to keep the history clean but I usually do not.

A Google search could have been https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+merge+master+into+my+branch.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! What does "origin" mean when merging like this? How is it different from merging branch A into master?

Comment: Updated my post with an explanation.

Comment: To answer your question, this is basically the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`git checkout A`
`git rebase master`

This will make your branch A on the top of master and branch A would have all changes done on master.

Make sure to `pull` latest branches before doing this

Answer (score 0):

To update changes made in the main branch to another branch in Git, you can use the following steps:

1. First, make sure you are on the branch where you want to apply the changes. You can switch branches using the command:

   ```
   git checkout <branch_name>
   ```
2. Then, merge the changes from the main branch into your current branch using:

   ```
   git merge main
   ```
3. Resolve any merge conflicts if they occur. Git will prompt you to resolve conflicts if there are any conflicting changes between the branches.
4. Once the merge is successful and any conflicts are resolved, commit the changes to the branch:

   ```
   git commit -m "Merged changes from main branch"
   ```
5. Finally, push the changes to the remote repository if you want to update the branch there:

   ```
   git push origin <branch_name>
   ```

These steps will update your current branch with the changes from the main branch. Make sure to replace `<branch_name>` with the name of the branch you want to update.